# Running UIMA annotators in parallel

Tags: uima

We have a UIMAFit pipeline with multiple independent annotators, looking for an approach to  execute them in parallel. Please suggest.
How about below approach

1)Create multiple analysis engine by grouping annotators
2)Get instances of Jcas from pool and initialize them with same text.
3)Use java thread executor framework to run analysis engine in parallel.
4)Merge Jcas

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use CpePipeline? http://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-2.1.0/api/org/apache/uima/fit/cpe/CpePipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

Following link may be helpful for this case.
http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=2247

But, it seems to be xml based execution of annotators not using uimafit.